# How can I make a regular expression for IP address with Subnetmask?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, http, networking, ip

I have IP address list like this:

```
180.183.0.0/16
180.210.216.0/22
180.214.192.0/19
182.52.0.0/15
...(400 more)
```

How can I make a  regular expression for IP address with Subnetmask?

**Why I want to get this.**

I have a website with Load Balancer(I can't change any config in server), my client wants to deny access from specific country access.
I use .htaccess like this.

```
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "59\.(5[6-9]|6[0-1])\.[0-9]+\." denyIP
order allow,deny
allow from all
deny from env=denyIP
```

Comment: What is it exactly that you need? If the list only has IP addresses, why do you want a regular expression for IP addresses. Maybe what you want is a regex to find **certain** addresses? In that case please complete the question with the specification of the ones you want to filter

Comment: You reminded me of [this challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11770/writing-firewall-rules) :p

Comment: If it's available, I'd actually suggest using something a little more robust such as `iptables` to deny access to an IP/IP-range. With htaccess, the requests still come in and are processed by your web-server (like Apache, for instance) - then they're blocked. With iptables, they're blocked before they actually make it to any applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the list of address in your sample text these expressions will match the requested ranges by using alternation to match numeric ranges. Unfortunately they'll need to be constructed individually because of how a regular expression doesn't really evaluate the text. To match a `182.52` or `182.53` string you'd use a regex which contains the desired sub-strings and it would look like `182.5[23]`.

- 180.183.0.0/16 has a range 180.183.0.1 - 180.183.255.254

  - `^180\.183\.(?:[0-9]{1,2}|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.(?:[1-9][0-9]?|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-4])$` [image]
- 180.210.216.0/22 has a range 180.183.0.1 - 180.183.3.254

  - `^180\.210\.[0-3]\.(?:[1-9][0-9]?|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-4])$` [image]
- 180.214.192.0/19 has a range 180.183.0.1 - 180.183.31.254

  - `^180\.214\.(?:[0-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\.(?:[1-9][0-9]?|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-4])$` [image]
- 182.52.0.0/15 has a range 182.52.0.1 - 182.53.255.254

  - `^182\.5[23]\.(?:[0-9]{1,2}|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.(?:[1-9][0-9]?|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-4])$` [image]

Comment: Thanks, it helps a lots. I wish I can use like this `deny from 180.210.216.0/22` in SetEnvIf...